# GradientBoostingClassifier implementation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to implement Gradient Boosting Classifier to my Titanic ML solution based on sklearn library.

I use VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried:

```
# Splitting the Training Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

predictors = train.drop(['Survived', 'PassengerId'], axis=1)
target = train["Survived"]
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(predictors, 
target, test_size = 0.22, random_state = 0)

# Gradient Boosting Classifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

gbk = GradientBoostingClassifier()
gbk.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

..which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py", line 1395, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'], dtype=DTYPE)
  File "/home/sj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 756, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator)
  File "/home/sj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "/home/sj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Baby'
```

Help would be appreciated. I'm quite new to DS.

Comment: Please experiment a little to see how things *look* before finalizing your post; your error trace was practically unreadable (fixed it for you this time). Also, avoid including code which comes *after* the error, since it is irrelevant to the issue (it is never executed) and just creates clutter (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may a non numerical values in your train data. Your classifier can take numerical inputs. That's why it tries to convert a string, here `'Baby'`, to a float. As this operation is not supported, it fails.

Maybe look again at your data.

Comment: Yes, true. I've forgot to map my AgeGroup feature into numeric.